# ExifInterface: Invalid image.java.io.IOException

Tags: android

I want to display images from mobile gallery in Activity but i am getting below Error.

Error Log :

```
ExifInterface: Invalid image.java.io.IOException: Invalid marker: 89
    at android.media.ExifInterface.getJpegAttributes(ExifInterface.java:1607)
    at android.media.ExifInterface.loadAttributes(ExifInterface.java:1335)
    at android.media.ExifInterface.<init>(ExifInterface.java:1052)
    at com.squareup.picasso.FileRequestHandler.getFileExifRotation(FileRequestHandler.java:46)
    at com.squareup.picasso.FileRequestHandler.load(FileRequestHandler.java:42)
    at com.squareup.picasso.BitmapHunter.hunt(BitmapHunter.java:206)
    at com.squareup.picasso.BitmapHunter.run(BitmapHunter.java:159)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
    at com.squareup.picasso.Utils$PicassoThread.run(Utils.java:411)
```

Fragment where i want to display images : I have created adapter class also

```
 super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    mGroupMedia = (GroupMedia) getActivity();

    imageFileList = new ArrayList<>();

    //Get Data
    GROUP_ID = mGroupMedia.getIntent().getStringExtra("GROUP_ID");
    IS_ADMIN = mGroupMedia.getIntent().getStringExtra("IS_ADMIN");
    GROUP_NAME = mGroupMedia.getIntent().getStringExtra("GROUP_NAME");
    realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    mCurrentGroup = RealmController.with(this).getGroup(Integer.parseInt(GROUP_ID));

    groupsMessages = new ArrayList<>();
    RealmResults<GroupMessages> x_groupsMessages = RealmController.with(mGroupMedia).getAllGroupMessages(Integer.parseInt(GROUP_ID));
    groupsMessages.addAll(x_groupsMessages);

    mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(mGroupMedia);

    mProgressDialog.setCancelable(true);

    final File Folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/folder");
    final File videosFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/folder/Images");
    final File grouopFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/folder/Images/"+GROUP_NAME);


    for(int i=0; i<groupsMessages.size(); i++){

        final File videoFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/folder/Images/"+GROUP_NAME+"/"+groupsMessages.get(i).getLink());

        if(Folder.exists() && videosFolder.exists() && grouopFolder.exists() && videoFile.exists()){

            if(!groupsMessages.get(i).getLink().trim().equals("")) {
                imageFileList.add(groupsMessages.get(i));

                Log.e("Video", "Video : " + videoFile.getAbsolutePath() + "");
            }
        }

    }

    Log.e("Video","Size : "+imageFileList.size());

    //Send data to VideoListAdapter
    imageFragmentGVAdapter = new ImageFragmentGVAdapter(mGroupMedia, imageFileList, GROUP_NAME);
    photosGridView.setAdapter(imageFragmentGVAdapter);
```

in adapter class i am creating view with grid layout

Comment: Okay, that's a stacktrace. Hard to help without seeing your actual code

Comment: i have uploaded my code. can you help me now

Comment: I'm not seeing where you use Picasso to load files here

Comment: in my adapter class

Comment: Please see about a [mcve]

Comment: i have followed same steps for Video folder also and that is working properly but i dont know why am getting ExifInterface: Invalid image.java.io.IOException while loading images from gallery

Comment: Did you find this yet? https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/1504

Comment: yeah i have checked that. and i have also compile my project with 'com.android.support:exifinterface:25.1.0'

Comment: Try the latest? `com.android.support:exifinterface:25.2.0`

Comment: still getting same error

Comment: You should show the code where you use the ExifInterface class.

Comment: This is for one corrupted image only? Try other images.

Comment: Hi! I have the same error, did you manage to fix it?